# ASP.NET MVC2 on .NET 4.0: is [ValidateInput(false)] enough?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, request-validation

Good day!

I plan to upgrade my ASP.NET MVC 2 application to .NET 4.0, and have a couple of questions:

1. Is having `[ValidateInput(false)]` on action enough to accept HTML, or I need to set `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>` as described here: [ASP.NET 4 Breaking Changes](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770147)
2. How it will work if I upgrade ASP.NET MVC to version 3 (in addition to uprading to .NET 4.0)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You need to set `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>` as well in ASP.NET 4.0.
2. The same as in ASP.NET MVC 2 (.NET 4.0) but in addition you have more fine grained control with the [`[AllowHtml]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute.aspx) attribute which could be placed on a single property of your view model instead of disabling validation for the entire request:

   ```
   public class MyViewModel
   {
       [AllowHtml]
       public string SomeHtmlProperty { get; set; }

       public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
   }
   ```

and have a controller action like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(MyViewModel model) { ... }
```